# PATH issue: Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching

Tags: ubuntu, apache-spark, path

I updated my PATH to look like this:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH:/home/username/Installs/Spark/bin"
```

I *think* it worked as I managed to call spark-shell from a different folder (although I'm wondering if I'm going crazy and it was really from the bin folder). However after rebooting Ubuntu it no longer seems to work. Why?

```
Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/home/username', '/usr/local/bin']
/usr/local/bin/spark-shell: line 57: /bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH:/home/username/Installs/Spark/bin"
```

would enable to run the executable scripts like `spark-shell`, `spark-submit`, `pyspark` etc. without need to give full path to the scripts.

Besides setting `PATH`, you would need to set

```
SPARK_HOME=/home/username/Installs/Spark
```

which is used internally when you start *spark cluster* or when you use `spark-submit`.

If you are setting the variables in `.bashrc` file, you need `export` keyword too as

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/username/Installs/Spark
```

and if you don't want to reboot Ubuntu to test it worked type

```
. ~/.profile
```

into the command line then try your spark command.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you should execute:

```
pip install pyspark --user
```