# SPARK_HOME error when using subprocess in GKE

Tags: python, pyspark, google-kubernetes-engine

I am new to Spark and I want to deploy a PySpark script to GKE.
The program is simply calling another sub python file `sub.py` for creating a database and a table in a GCS bucket.

`main.py`:

```py
import os
import sys
import subprocess

# use subprocess to call the sub.py, real url has been masked
logs = subprocess.check_output("python <xxx>/sub.py", 
                                shell=True).decode('utf8')
# print the logs
print(logs)
```

`sub.py` :

```py
from os.path import abspath
import subprocess,sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField


# Create a DB named myDB and a table named myTable
if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
        .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()
    spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myDB LOCATION 'gs://my-bucket/myDB'")
    spark.sql("use myDB")
    spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable (key INT, value STRING) USING HIVE")
    spark.stop()
```

The yaml file is:

```
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: Python
  pythonVersion: "2"
  mode: cluster
  image: "gcr.io/<GCP-Project-Name>/<Image-of-these-2-py-files>"
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  mainApplicationFile: local:///opt/<xxx>/main.py
  sparkVersion: "3.0.0"
  hadoopConf:
    fs.gs.impl: com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem
    fs.gs.project.id: <GCP-Project-Name>
    fs.gs.system.bucket: <my-bucket>
    google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable: "true"
    google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile: <xxx>/my-service-acct-key.json
  restartPolicy:
    ...
  driver:
    ...
  executor:
    ...
```

#### Questions

I encounter the error as below

```
File "xxx/sub.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyspark.sql.functions import SparkSession
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/find_spark_home.py", line 68
    print("Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching {0}".format(paths), file=sys.stderr)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/examples/src/main/python/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    shell=True).decode('utf8')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 487, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'python <xxx>/sub.py' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I could not understand why there is `SPARK_HOME` problem.
But when I trying to call the `sub.py` from yaml file, it works.
I am wondering the difference between

- calling a python from Yaml
- from subprocess

and how to solve this problem if I have to use `main.py` to call the `sub.py` .

Comment: there is a similar behaviour in [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991888/path-issue-could-not-find-valid-spark-home-while-searching) but still unsure about how to fix this path while using the subprocess scenario.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to want to deploy the PySpark script in GKE instead of using the product explicitly developed in GCP to run those kind of scripts? I recommend you to take a look at [Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc). There are a bunch of [tutorials on how to use PySpark with Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials#apache-spark), and using the explicit product designed to run those scripts might mitigate the issues you're finding.

Comment: @Jofre Thanks for your comments and information. Actually Dataproc is one of the consideration and I have verified it can solve the subprocess problem. The reason i want PySpark on GKE is trying to make the app deployed across different Cloud Service Provider eg. Azure/Aws