# Windows Spark_Home error with pyspark during spark-submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm getting the error below when running spark-submit on a simple python script to import sparksession. I have the `Spark_Home` user variable set to 'C:\Spark\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2'; ENV path in user variables set to C:\Spark\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\bin; `HADOOP_HOME` path set to folder with WINUTILS.

Did everything here: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-spark-on-windows-10

Full code below.

Respectfully I tried to [PATH issue: Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991888/path-issue-could-not-find-valid-spark-home-while-searching?rq=1) this did not work, I'm on windows. This is work related, I'm new to stackoverflow and Spark. Thx!!

```
C:\Spark\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\bin>spark-submit C:\Spark\PYScripts\New.py
21/06/21 16:44:22 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Spark/PYScripts/New.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\find_spark_home.py", line 68
    print("Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching {0}".format(paths), file=sys.stderr)
                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `findspark`.

```
import findspark
findspark.find()

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("Spark") \
    .getOrCreate()
```